# How to know if my app can use SAML?

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-server-2012-r2

Sorry for my non specific question but I'm very confused on this part, we're changing some applications on my work from LDAP authentication to another one based on SAML, so the security engineer team asked me if my app can implement SAML, but that's the part that I don't get it.

My App is wrote on asp.net 4.0 and using IIS 8, do you have any idea how can I start to go deeper on this? I'd really appreciate the help u_u

Comment: the answer is yes, going deeper is what you have to do

Comment: Yes to what?, That's the app is able to use SAML? There's a way to verify this? I already search SAML info, but everything that I found is about to mount like an app in ISS with a certificate, that's the tricky part, the security team is going to do the changes to the code, but I need just to confirm if it's is able to use it.

Comment: http: // bfy . tw/GV6m      <------   here you go